# How can I edit the raw HTML for a message in the web client for Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I can't find any options to edit the HTML in the web client of Microsoft Outlook. Is that possible, or would I have to download a dedicated client program?

Comment: JFTR, here are some links:
https://www.outlook-apps.com/insert-html-to-outlook-emails
https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/edit-html-source-code-email.htm#quickinstall
https://www.werockyourweb.com/community/edit-source-in-outlook-emails/#comment-18745
https://superuser.com/questions/1747163/inject-html-code-into-outlook-email

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any methods to edit the raw HTML in the web mailbox. Here is some information about edit the raw HTML in Outlook desktop client, for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a860991f-a3ca-4136-9e4d-5e4df7a5ee27/why-we-do-not-have-a-html-editor?forum=outlook