# Inject HTML code into Outlook email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, html, source-code

Is there an even easier (or maybe a little more user-friendly) way to inject a few lines of HTML source code into an Outlook email, than using a macro like shown over there:

[Edit the HTML source code while composing a message in Outlook](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/edit-html-source-code-email.htm#quickinstall)

Outlook HTML source code window of the above macro:
[image: HTML source code window of the above macro]

**Edit 1:** Here are some more links on this.
It seems that there is no easier way around to be found on the web.

https://www.outlook-apps.com/insert-html-to-outlook-emails
https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/edit-html-source-code-email.htm#quickinstall
https://www.werockyourweb.com/community/edit-source-in-outlook-emails/#comment-18745

The code from the last link (see below) is pretty neat. It switches between HTML source and WYSIWYG inside the Outlook message window itself. However, there seem to be problems when switching back to WYSIWYG and Outlook obviously interpreting some of the code as mail text (or something).

> May 23, 2008 9:07 am The Other Way
>
> Use these macros to switch the current email between source view and
> HTML view.
>
> The first will take a HTML message and convert it into a text message,
> retaining the tags.
>
> Once you’ve edited it and are ready to send, the 2nd one will convert
> the text message back to HTML.
>
> Evil Overlord
>
> ```
> Sub HTML2Text()
> Dim objApp As Application
> Dim objItem As MailItem
> Dim strBody As String
> Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
> Set objItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
> If (objItem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML) Then
> strBody = objItem.HTMLBody
> objItem.HTMLBody = ""
> objItem.Body = strBody
> objItem.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
> End If
> End Sub
>
> Sub Text2HTML()
> Dim objApp As Application
> Dim objItem As MailItem
> Dim strBody As String
> Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
> Set objItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
> If (objItem.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain) Then
> strBody = objItem.Body
> objItem.Body = ""
> objItem.HTMLBody = strBody
> objItem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
> End If
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: You could take the time to learn a little VBA.  That macro you point to already shows you how to do all of the "hard part".  Instead of putting all of the source text into an edit box, you would simply operate on it like a string and save it using the part of the code that has either "ApplySend" or "Apply".

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.werockyourweb.com/community/edit-source-in-outlook-emails/) is a surprisingly straightforward approach:

> I wrote my code in notepad++, viewed it in Chrome, and then copied it into my email. Worked beautifully!

I modified this and **use [BlueGriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/#download)** instead to edit the source code of any part of an Outlook email draft. This has the advantage that you can copy the WYSIWYG part in both directions from and to Outlook. Plus, it's a portable program.